# Why is my regex not working

Tags: regex, vb.net, function

I tried myself for the first time at an regex expression.

Why doesnt it show the messagebox (*"Pls insert a valid mail!"*) if the text is wrong?

I imported the Regex

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

then i wrote my function

```
Function emailAddressChecker() As Boolean
    Dim regex As Regex = Nothing
    Dim regExPattern As String = "^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$"
    Dim emailAddress = txtbx_neueEmail.Text
    If Regex.IsMatch(emailAddress, regExPattern) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
        MessageBox.Show("Pls insert a valid mail!")
        txtbx_neueEmail.Text = ""
    End If
End Function
```

then i used my function in an event

```
Private Sub btn_BestaetigeBearbeitung_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btn_BestaetigeBearbeitung.Click
    If combx_Auswahl.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        emailAddressChecker()
        If emailAddressChecker() = True 
            MessageBox.Show("Hallo!")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("")
        End If
```

Comment: `Return False` is above `MessageBox.Show`, hence `MessageBox.Show` never executes. You need to put `MessageBox.Show` above `Return False` to show message box.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto omg so simple! iam sry i bothered ur time, this is just emberassing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is executed after a `Return` statement, you should change you code order like this:

```
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Pls insert a valid mail!")
    txtbx_neueEmail.Text = ""
    Return False
End If
```